# AudioKit issue, mic not sensitive enough

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I have an issue where the microphone on my 6s will only give me an output if I am right in front of the microphone. I'd like to change the sensitivity so that it will read a frequency even from a couple of feet distance.

This is how I initialize the AKMicrophone:

```
AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
mic = AKMicrophone()
tracker = AKFrequencyTracker.init(mic)
silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try sticking a booster before the tracker:

```
mic = AKMicrophone()
boostedMic = AKBooster(mic, gain: 5)
tracker = AKFrequencyTracker.init(boostedMic)
silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)
```

Adjust the constant "5" accordingly.  HTH!